# Using Excel VBA to pull datasets from internet explorer - how to interact with save/open/save as pop up

Tags: html, vba, internet-explorer, excel

I've put all of my code here so you can take a look at my problem. This code has mainly been hashed together from a mixture of my knowledge, books, the internet and friends. Basically it all seems to be working until I get the internet explorer pop-up asking if I want to open the file or save it.

Ideally I'd like to save without opening, in a specific location. I've spent a couple of days looking on and off to try to find how to do this and I'm struggling. Thanks in advance!!

```
Sub WebScraper()

Dim URL As String
Dim postcode As String

'set variables
URL = "http://neighbourhood.statistics.gov.uk/dissemination/"

Set inputs = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Parameters")

Set IE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
    IE.Visible = True

RowCounter = 2
ColumnCounter = 1

Do Until IsEmpty(inputs.Cells(RowCounter, 1).Value)

    postcode = inputs.Cells(RowCounter, 1).Value

    'connect to ONS
    Set objIE = ONSConnect(IE, URL)

    'submit postcode
    'Call submitPostcode(objIE, postcode)
    tableURL = getTableURL(objIE, postcode)

    'scrape table to excel
    Call GetTable(tableURL)

    'increment counter
    RowCounter = RowCounter + 1

    'clear postcode variable
    postcode = ""

Loop

    Call quitIE(objIE.Application)

End Sub


'sub to quit IE and cleanup
Sub quitIE(obj As Object)
    obj.Navigate ("javascript: closeChildWindowsAndLogout();")
    obj.Quit
End Sub

'sub to tell macro to wait while page loads
Sub Wait(obj As Object)
    Do While obj.Busy: Loop
    Do While obj.ReadyState <> 4:   Loop
    Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:01"))
End Sub



Function ONSConnect(IE, URL As String)

    IE.Navigate URL
    Wait (IE.Application)
    Set ONSConnect = IE

End Function




Function getTableURL(objIE, postcode As String)

Dim postcodeBox As Object
Dim radioButton As Object
Dim showAll As Object
Dim i As Integer
Dim fileExists As Boolean

Set postcodeBox = objIE.Document.getElementById("areaSearchText")
Set radioButton = objIE.Document.getElementById("L141")
Set searchBtns = objIE.Document.getElementsBytagname("BUTTON")

''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''' 
'enter postcode
postcodeBox.Value = postcode

'''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
'check radiobutton
radioButton.Checked = True

'''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
'search
For Each ele In searchBtns
    If ele.Title Like "Search for statistics on an area" Then
        ele.Click
    End If
Next

Wait (objIE.Application)

''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
' Navigate to crime and safety page
i = 0
Set showAll = Nothing

While i < objIE.Document.Links.length And showAll Is Nothing

If InStr(objIE.Document.Links(i).innerText, "Crime and Safety") > 0 Then
    Set showAll = objIE.Document.Links(i)
End If

i = i + 1

Wend

If Not showAll Is Nothing Then
showAll.Click
End If

Wait (objIE.Application)

''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
' Navigate to fire and rescue service page
i = 0
Set showAll = Nothing

While i < objIE.Document.Links.length And showAll Is Nothing

    If InStr(objIE.Document.Links(i).innerText, "Fire and Rescue Service") > 0 Then
        Set showAll = objIE.Document.Links(i)
    End If

i = i + 1

Wend

If Not showAll Is Nothing Then
    showAll.Click
End If

Wait (objIE.Application)

'''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
'we can now get the URL of the tables and pass this to the scraper
'

'getTableURL = objIE.locationurl


''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
objIE.Document.all("downloadTable").Click

Wait (objIE.Application)


End Function



Sub GetTable(URL)

With Sheets("Data").QueryTables.Add(Connection:= _
    "URL;" & URL, Destination:=Sheets("Data").Range("$A$1")) _
    .Name = "data"
    .FieldNames = True
    .RowNumbers = False
    .FillAdjacentFormulas = False
    .PreserveFormatting = True
    .RefreshOnFileOpen = False
    .BackgroundQuery = True
    .RefreshStyle = xlInsertDeleteCells
    .SavePassword = False
    .SaveData = True
    .AdjustColumnWidth = True
    .RefreshPeriod = 0
    .WebSelectionType = xlSpecifiedTables
    .WebFormatting = xlWebFormattingNone
    .WebTables = "5"
    .WebPreFormattedTextToColumns = True
    .WebConsecutiveDelimitersAsOne = True
    .WebSingleBlockTextImport = False
    .WebDisableDateRecognition = False
    .WebDisableRedirections = False
    .Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False
End With

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

since i cant add a comment yet something like this maybe usefull

```
Sub GetTable()
```

Dim putwks As Worksheet
Dim pstcde As String, newUrl As String

Set putwks = Worksheets("parameters")
pstcde = putwks.Range("A1").Value
newUrl = "http://neighbourhood.statistics.gov.uk/dissemination/NeighbourhoodProfile.do?a=7&b=6275188&c=" & pstcde & "&g=6471253&i=1001x1012&j=6312789&m=1&p=1&q=1&r=0&s=1417495287339&enc=1&tab=7&inWales=false"
'to show the entire url
MsgBox newurl

where your url goes directly to your page you need according to what you put in a1 on your parameter sheet